# Symfony 3.4 - non existent service when installing FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've just started a new blank project using Symfony 3.4 and first of all configured FOSUserBundle following this [Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) page.

I've tried two times deleting all and start from scratch again but I got this error during clearing cache:

```
In CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 31:

  The service "security.authentication.provider.dao.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fos_user.user_checker".
```

**config.yml**

```
[...]
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: smtp.mailtrap.io
    mailer_user: ***
    mailer_password: ***
    secret: ***
```

**routing.yml**

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            user_checker: fos_user.user_checker
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Obviously I've add `new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),` in `AppKernel.php`

```
$bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        ];
```

I'm using version `2.0` of `FOSUserBundle` and `Symfony 3.4`.

Comment: have you tried to comment-out the line `user_checker: fos_user.user_checker` from `security.yml` and refresh?

Comment: Damn, this solve the error. but.. why there is this parameter in documentation?

Comment: I ask the same... Why is in the documentation... :S

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2855

Answer (score 3):

For Symfony 3.4 and FOSUserBundle 2.1 this issue appears to continue to exist.

Fix:
Change the following in security.yml

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            user_checker: fos_user.user_checker
```

to

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            user_checker: security.user_checker
```